# How to interpret the following output given by Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn about the Lambda function in Python by messing up the code to observe what errors Python would throw in various scenarios.
Can anyone please explain what exactly is the meaning of following message displayed by the IDLE and how to interpret it?

```py
def myfunc(n):
    return lambda a:a*n

myfunc(2)
```

error:

> (function myfunc.. at 0x037800B8)

Comment: Your return statement should be indented.

Answer (score 3):

Your defined function returns a lambda function. This isn't an error message, it is printing the lambda function object.

Comment: And to expand on this, the return value here is a [lambda] function that itself will take a number and multiply it by 2. Similarly, doing `tripler = myfunc(3)` will return (into the `tripler` variable) a [lambda] function that takes a number and triples it. So you can then do `print(tripler(10))` and it will print 30.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you mis-typed your indentation, and that the code snippet was

```py
def myfunc(n):
    return lambda a:a*n

myfunc(2)
```

the `lambda` operator here returns a function doing `x-> n*x`. So `myfunc` is essentially a function that returns another function.

Your code is legit, and the output of python is only the description of the object `myfunc(2)` returned. Let's break it down:

- the leading `function` confirms that you get a function
- The `myfunc.<locals>.lambda` is the *name* of the object. That part explains that this function was created in `myfunc`, using some of the parameters of `myfunc` (note that you use `n` in the lambda definition`. This is called a [closure](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Closures).
- the `0x037800B8` is the memory adress this python object is stored at

Answer (score 1):

You should interpret this as a function object or a functor.
`myfunc.<locals>.<lambda>` its just says that it is a local variable of `myfunc` and its a lambda function.

```
myfunc(2) # is a function object
print(myfunc(2)(3)) # prints 6 which is 3 * 2
```

This function stores the inner variable n = 2 and then returns the called value. This concept is called functional closure.

You can get into more detail if you disassembled and dive deep if you want.

```
from dis import dis
def myfunc(n):
    return lambda a:a*n
dis(myfunc)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
➜  codebase git:(master) ✗ python temp.py
  3           0 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (n)
              2 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <lambda> at 0x7fc5f671f5d0, file "temp.py", line 3>)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('myfunc.<locals>.<lambda>')
              8 MAKE_FUNCTION            8
             10 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <lambda> at 0x7fc5f671f5d0, file "temp.py", line 3>:
  3           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_DEREF               0 (n)
              4 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that your command

```
myfunc(2)
```

returned a function (namely, a lambda function in myfunc scope). `0x037800B8` is its address in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're returning the entire lambda function rather than returning the result. To return the lambda function's value, surround it with parenthesis like so:

```
>>> def myfunc(n):
    return (lambda a: a*n)(n)

>>> myfunc(2)
4
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply returning a reference to a function. Lambdas were born to make short functions, short to type, avoiding the boilerplate of writing "def function(): .."

Try looking at the following tutorial to get the basics:

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp